# Posterior distribution of two i.i.d. uniform r.v. given their difference with graphical intuition

Tags: probability, expected-value, posterior, uniform-distribution, iid

I have two i.i.d. random variables, $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ which are uniformly distributed on the unit square. I need to compute the joint posterior distribution of these two variables, given their difference $m=\theta_1-\theta_2$, i.e. $f_{\theta|m}(\theta|m)$ where $\theta=(\theta_1,\theta_2)$. I then must use this posterior to compute the expectation of some function $g(\theta_1,\theta_2)$,
$$\mathbb{E}_{f_{\theta|m}}[g(\theta_1,\theta_2)]$$

I am having trouble computing the posterior distribution $f_{\theta|m}(\theta|m)$ and reconciling the results with a graphical intuition (see below). It would be great if you could also help me to set up the integral for the expectation with the relevant boundaries.

**My attempt**

Using Bayes' theorem we can write
$$f_{\theta|m}(\theta|m)=\frac{f_{m|\theta}(m|\theta)f_\theta(\theta)}{f_m(m)}$$
Now, $f_\theta(\theta)=1$ for all $(\theta_1,\theta_2) \in [0,1]\times[0,1]$. As for $f_{\theta|m}(m|\theta)$, this equals $1$ when $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ fall in the line $\theta_1-\theta_2=m$, and zero otherwise, so $f_{\theta|m}(m|\theta)$ should just be the indicator $\mathbb{I}_{\{\theta_1-\theta_2=m\}}(\theta_1,\theta_2)$. I computed the denominator using the convolution formula, and obtained $f_m(m)=1-|m|$ for $m \in [-1,1]$. Putting everything together,
$$f_{\theta|m}(\theta|m)=\frac{1}{1-|m|} \ \ \text{ if } \ \theta_1-\theta_2=m$$
with $m \in [-1,1]$, and zero otherwise. I was wondering if this formula is correct and, if so, if there is a more explicit way to write the support of $(\theta_1,\theta_2)$ in terms of intervals. I need this because I must use this posterior to compute the expectation of a function of $\theta$ and I need to specify the limits of integration.

Moreover, I was not able to reconcile this result with a graphical intuition. Indeed, after learning $m$ I would expect that the random vector $(\theta_1,\theta_2)$ is uniformly distributed on the line segment $m=\theta_1-\theta_2$, with $\theta_1 \in [0,m+1]$ and $\theta_2 \in [-m,1]$ for $m<0$ in the figure below (and similarly, with $\theta_1 \in [m,1]$ and $\theta_2 \in [0,1-m]$ for $m>0$). This segment has length (Pythagorean theorem) $\sqrt{2}(1+m)$ if $m<0$ and $\sqrt{2}(1-m)$ if $m>0$, so $\sqrt{2}(1-|m|)$ suggesting a density of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}(1-|m|)}$, which is similar to what I got with the previous method, but not identical, as we have this additional $\sqrt{2}$ which I cannot find an interpretation for.

Thank you in advance!

[image: Unit square]

Comment: I think the explanation is that the factor of $\sqrt 2$ is eliminated when you project onto the x-axis or y-axis. Imagine we pick a point uniformly at random from the line segment between (0,0) and (1,1). Then the probability that the point lies on a subsegment of length $l$ is $\frac{l}{\sqrt{2}}$, but the probability that the x coordinate of the point lies on subinterval of [0, 1] of length $m$ is just $m$, because the projection shrinks the domain by a factor of $\sqrt 2$.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/573959 answers your question and helps refine your (correct) intuition.